# how can i extract data from this discount.txt file to calculate discount?

Tags: python

Write a Python program that, for every transaction, takes input on the customer ID and the total sale amount in the transaction. It then reads a text file called discount. text that stores information on the discount on sales amount as shown in Table 1 above. The text file stores the information in a plain text format as follows.

```
Less than $100 --> 0%
From $100 up to less than $500 --> 10%
From $500 up to less than $1,000 --> $40 PLUS 20%
From $1,000 up to less than $2,000 --> $140 PLUS 30%
$2,000 and above --> $440 PLUS 40%
```

Comment: I don't see a python program

Comment: At the end of each transaction the following information is written (appended) out in a file called sales.txt. The same information is also displayed on screen.


Customer ID: 1
Total sale amount: 110
Discount amount: 1
Discounted sale amount: 109

Reward point: 1
Additional discount: 0
Additional discounted sale amount: 109
Cumulative sale amount for the next reward point: 10


Final sale amount: 109

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: created a discount.txt file and used this code
my_file = open('discount.txt')
condition = my_file.readline()

print (condition)

Comment: but don't know where to start it from

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import division

class Discount(object):

    def __init__(self,min_value=0,max_value=0,flat_discount=0,discount=0):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.flat_discount = flat_discount
        self.discount = discount

    def is_applicable(self,amount):
        if amount > self.max_value:
            return False
        if amount >= self.min_value and amount <= self.max_value:
            return True


    def apply_discount(self,bill_amount):

        if bill_amount >= self.min_value and bill_amount <= self.max_value:
            final_bill = 0
            amount_discount = bill_amount * (self.discount / 100)
            final_bill += bill_amount - amount_discount
            if self.flat_discount != 0:
                final_bill = final_bill - self.flat_discount

        return final_bill


d0 = Discount()
d1 = Discount(9,100,0,0)
d2 = Discount(101,500,0,10)
d3 = Discount(501,1000,40,20)
d4 = Discount(1001,2000,140,30)
d5 = Discount(2001,99999999,440,40)

amounts = [100,434,4242,2221,424,667,22]

for amount in amounts:
    for discount_offer in [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]:
        if discount_offer.is_applicable(amount):
            print "Final Price for %s is %s" % (amount, discount_offer.apply_discount(amount))
```

You will have to store the discount data into some form that is more easily readable by Python. I suggest [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

The config would look something like

```
[Discount1]
min_value = '0'
max_value = '100'
discount = '0'
flat_discount = '0'
```

which you could then use to create those objects

Comment: Then write a parser for it! Human written files are going to be a pain. You might write a parser that reads `Less than $100 --> 0%` and understands it, but sooner or later, some human will change that to `Between $0 and $100 --> 0.0%` and you will be back to square one

Comment: i am not allowed to do it. i need to do it with human written files